# Translating "not that good"

Tags: traducción

Estoy escribiendo un cuento para mi clase de español. Mi cuento es sobre un pingüino.

How would this be translated

> He is a good skier, but not that good.

I am trying to use not that good to state how he is not good enough to ski off of a huge mountain.

Comment: "...pero no tan bueno" tal vez?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Algunas alternativas:

> Él es un buen esquiador, pero no tan bueno.
>
> Él es buen esquiador, pero no tanto.
>
> Es buen esquiador, pero le falta.

Si quieres incluir en la misma frase la parte referente a la gran montaña puedes usar:

> Él es buen esquiador pero no tan bueno como para esquiar en una gran montaña.
>
> Es buen esquiador pero no tanto como para esquiar en una gran montaña.
>
> Es buen esquiador pero le falta experiencia/talento/valor/entrenamiento/nivel como para esquiar en una gran montaña.
>
> Él es bastante bueno esquiando, pero no tan bueno como para esquiar en una gran montaña.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "Él es *bastante* buen esquiador, pero no *muy* bueno."

A literal translation would be: He is a "pretty good" skier but not "great."

Comment: *bastante buen* no es idiomático. ¿En donde se usa?

Comment: I'm sorry Tom but that sentence is not correct. Perhaps you could say "Él es **bastante bueno** esquiando, pero no tan bueno" but you can't say ".. un bastante..."

Comment: @DGaleano: OK, removed the "un." Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ustanak: Creo que en America. Soy norte americano, y hablo un "espanol" americano.

Answer (score -2):

> Él no es tan buen esquiador de montañas grandes, todavía es un
>   aprendiz

- Aprendiz:sustantivo.
- Aprender: verbo.
- Novato y aprendiz son sinónimos.